# node-gyp - how to generate a Visual Studio project with NatVis file included

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, node-gyp, gyp

Is it possible to generate a Visual Studio project with `node-gyp` such that it will include a specified `.natvis` file?
When I manually add a `.natvis` file to my C++ project, I see that my `.vcxproj` file is updated with the following block:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Natvis Include="filename.natvis">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Natvis>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is it possible to configure my `binding.gyp` file to generate such block?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to specify for the linker which NATVIS file to use. Here is how I specified it in my `.gyp` file:

```
"conditions": [
  [
    "OS=='win'",
    {
      "configurations": {
        "Debug": {
          "msvs_settings": {
            "VCLinkerTool": {
              "AdditionalOptions": ['/NATVIS:"$(SolutionDir)..\\natvis\myfile.natvis"']
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
]
```